# Composition in UML for a field of type Dictionary<Bar, Quux>

Tags: dictionary, uml, composition

I would like to model the following code using a UML diagram:

```
public class Bar { /* ... */ }
public class Quux { /* ... */ }
public class Foo {
    public Dictionary<Bar, Quux> aField;
}
```

The `Foo` class is **composed** of many `Bar`/`Quux` couples, in the sense of composition vs. aggregation. **How should I represent that using UML?**

The only "correct" thing I can think of is rather cumbersome:

[image: Foo is composed of KeyValuePair<Bar, Quux>, which has a 1-1 relation with Bar, and a 1-1 relation with Quux]

But I'd rather have something along the lines of this:

[image: Foo is composed of ... and the line splits, one line goes to Bar, and the other to Quux]

I could also use the perhaps-too-obvious solution showing the field in `Foo`, but I'd loose the **composition** information, and I'd like to have some line which visually connects  `Foo`, `Bar` and `Quux`:

[image: Putting the Dictionary<Bar, Quux> field in Foo, without any lines between the classes.]

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you put Key and Value in the first diagram? So in the first diagram, replace the top '1'  (next to Bar) with 'key' and the 1 next qo Quux with 'Value'.

The second diagram is not correct, because there can be multiple Bar's and multiple Quux's but the amount do not have to be equal; nor is there a relation between them.

Comment: Well, I want to avoid the big `KeyValuePair<Bar, Quux>` in my first diagram, because it's distracting and feels like an implementation detail wich shouldn't be there. My concern is not about the `key` and `value` labels, but more about how to represent the "composition using a dictionary/associative list/..." idea in an elegant way.

Comment: In that case I would go for the second solution ... maybe add next to Foo 'Dictionary' so it is clear that Bar and Quux have a relation. It may be not 100% UML but I'm sure everybody will know what is meant.

Comment: You might assign this as a stereotype to Foo: <<Dictionary>>

Comment: @observer Note that Foo might have multiple class variables, not only that dictionary.